# lsof returns "can't read vnode" error

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, lsof

On a Solaris 10 box, I am getting errors from `lsof`:

```
can't read vnode at 0x7d900000000
can't read vnode at 0x7b
```

But I have the same `lsof` binary in another similar Solaris 10 box where it doesn't give the same error.

On that other box, `lsof` successfully lists the open files information.

Has anybody else encountered the same problem and has been able to resolve it?

Snippet from full output:

```
$ lsof
lsof: WARNING: compiled for Solaris release 5.9; this is 5.10.
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
(unknown)     1     root  cwd                             can't read vnode at 0x7d900000000
(unknown)     1     root  rtd                             can't read vnode at 0x7b
(unknown)     9     root  cwd                             can't read vnode at 0x7d900000000
....
```

Output of `isainfo -kv` and `file`:

```
$ isainfo -kv
64-bit sparcv9 kernel modules
$ file `which lsof`
/usr/local/bin/lsof:    ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC Version 1, dynamically linked, stripped
```

Output of `uname -a` on the server where lsof works:

```
$ uname -a
SunOS server009 5.10 Generic_150400-26 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise
```

Output of `uname -a` on the server where lsof doesn't work:

```
$ uname -a
SunOS server043 5.10 Generic_150400-12 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V890
```

Comment: What is the full output of your `lsof` command, and what flags are you using with it?

Comment: No flags. I've added a snippet from full output to the original post.

Comment: Can we also see `isainfo -kv` and the output of `file` on your `lsof` binary?

Comment: added  `isainfo -kv` and `file` outputs.

Comment: Do you have the same outputs on the server that works, for comparison?

Comment: Yes, the output is exactly the same on the server that works.

Answer (score 2):

> lsof: WARNING: compiled for Solaris release 5.9; this is 5.10.

That sounds suspiciously like `lsof` tells you that it is broken and you need to rebuild the `lsof` binary from source (or in other words: upgrade ) to reliably work with your current Solaris version.

If that is not an option, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/alternatives-for-lsof-command) might help you work around the issue.

Comment: The same binary does work on another machine. I'll review that other page you cited. There maybe something useful there.

Comment: Post the output of `uname -a` from both servers.  Not all versions of Solaris 10 are the same.  And even if they are the same, file systems can differ - Solaris 9 didn't have ZFS, for example, so I suspect an `lsof` binary from Solaris 9 might have problems on Solaris 10, especially with ZFS.

Comment: i added the output of `uname -a`. Both systems do not have ZFS. Their is a slight difference in patch level but would that account for it?

Comment: It's not likely the patch level as the later machine is the one that works.  It could be hardware - the servers are different.  It could also be the environment.  But given it's an out-of-date version of `lsof`, the first thing I'd recommend doing is an update of `lsof`.

Comment: is there a place where i can get a binary for solaris 10 version of lsof?